# How to stop rxvt from spacing fonts miles apart?

Tags: fonts, msys, rxvt, kerning

I installed the latest release of MinGW/MSYS, and I like to use rxvt terminal over the boring windows command prompt. But this new build spaces the letters too much: most fonts I have tried are messed up - even Courier New (ttf), Consolas (ttf), or PC6X13 (fon).

I'm stuck with plain OLD Courier because at least it's readable. Any solutions out there? EASY solutions preferred, I don't feel like patching source code and re-compiling rxvt!

Comment: Good idea, it's not spaced out, but vertical lines appear between each letter as you type :(

Comment: EUREKA! Monaco.TTF is the solution. It seems that rxvt detected some wide glyphs in the other font files and spaced everything accordingly. But Monaco seems better behaved.

Comment: Well now I've decided that MinGW/MSYS doesn't cut the mustard and I'm using CygWin + PuTTYcyg. Forget about clunky old rxvt!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For rxvt, I found Courier New works (alas, no Consolas).
There's also Console 2: http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/  which works pretty well with bash (MSys) and CMD shells.

Comment: Thanks, I found Inconsolata to be OK on RXVT :)

Answer (score 1):

I like mintty. The only problem I've had with it so far is that if I use the Windows python rather than the cygwin version, the output is line buffered, but this is a small issue. Other than that, it seems to provide many of the comforts of a modern terminal, with no hassle at all.

However, I have no idea if it works with MinGW/MSYS (which I only realised you were asking about on re-reading your question!).

Comment: There's actually a very simple workaround for that problem with Win32 Python: invoke it with option -i.

This explicitly tells it to run in interactive mode. The reason it doesn't work otherwise is that it checks whether stdin is a console. With mintty and other pty-based terminals the answer is no, because Cygwin uses pipes to emulate ptys, so Python enters non-interactive mode.

(from http://code.google.com/p/mintty/issues/detail?id=56 )

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED 
New improved solution :

1. Download & install Monaco.TTF ~ freely available with judicious Google power
2. Adjust msys.bat thusly:

   `start %WD%rxvt -backspacekey^H -sl 2500 -fg White -bg Black -sr -fn Monaco-18 -tn msys -geometry 120x37 -e /bin/sh --login -i`

Answer (score 0):

I find that the "Dina" font seems to work pretty well, too.  Most of my other favorite monospaced fonts do not space correctly on MSYS RXVT (with one of several symptoms - either too far apart, too close (cutting off parts of letters), or with bars between chars).